# Wrong reading from bash

Tags: gpio

I'm reading a value on a GPIO pin (0/1) with bash (wiringPI).
Everything worked fine until now. I hooked up a button that I pressed and the raspberry read the value 1 and then 0 when I released it. 
But now sometimes I only get a 0 if there is absolutely nothing connected to the GPIO. When I connect something to it (even if it's just a wire with nothing on the other end) I'm getting sometimes 0 and sometimes 1.
What is happening? Did I mess up the GPIO?

Please help

Comment: Have you tried the pintest supplied with wiringPi http://wiringpi.com/the-gpio-utility/pin-test/

Answer (score 2):

hanging wire works as an antenna. it's absolutely correct to read random values from the port connected to the nothing, you should not worry about it much. when you use push button, you'd better use pull-ups or pull-downs to avoid input pin floating in the air:

[image]

Comment: The Raspberry Pi supports internal pull-up and pull-down resistors so the external pull-up you describe is not necessary if you use the internal pull-up.

Comment: Just to add. The value of the pin will be high (1) if not pressed. Once the button is pressed it will read low (0). Slightly unintuitive.

Comment: @Gerben you may flip the schematics vertically to replace pull-up with a pull-down, if you like.

Comment: But pull-ups are more energy efficient, I believe :-)